# Using bind as a method for currying

Tags: javascript, currying

I was watching a video on youtube about functional programming. They had gotten through some basic currying stuff (still trying to really grasp that), and then they showed a way that you could use bind as a "soft" curry-er.

```
function simpleURL(protocol, domain, path) {
  return protocol + "://" + domain + "/" + path;
}

var paths = ["search?query=dogs", "search?query=cats"];

/*
var urls = paths.map(function(path) {
  return simpleURL("http", "www.firefox.com", path);
});
*/

var urls = paths.map(simpleURL.bind(null, "http", "www.firefox.com"));

console.log(urls); // --> ["http://www.firefox.com/search?query=dogs", "http://www.firefox.com/search?query=cats"]
```

I understand the commented way of accomplishing things, but not the `urls` with bind. I know that bind returns another function, but I'm not picking up on how the current value being iterated of the array (i.e. the "path") is being set and used through bind.

Comment: bind pre-fills the arguments, later arguments will shift to the right when the bound function is called. if calling from a map, there are actually two more arguments passed to the bound callback: the index and the whole collection of paths. the only trick is the first argument to bind(), which like call/apply, sets _this_ for the function, instead of specifying a curried argument like the other arguments to bind perform...

Answer (score 3):

When you use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this:

```
simpleURL.bind(null, "http", "www.firefox.com")
```

it results into new function that is used as a callback function passed into `map`. This new function is invoked with two additional parameters: "http" and "www.firefox.com". So virtually it looks something like this:

```
paths.map(function(path) {
    return simpleURL.call(null, "http", "www.firefox.com", path);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returned by simpleURL.bind(null, "http", "www.firefox.com") works the same way as the original function, but protocol and domain are always equal to "http" and "www.firefox.com", and it now only takes one argument which is the value of path.

When you call the map function, it passes each value of the array to your new function and that value will become the value of path.